# Boxing as a form of fitness

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia, sports

Assalamu Alaykum
I've done some searching and so far have not found an opinion on boxing for fitness within Islam.

I've found that I am sound wrestler and have been looking for alternative means of training my stamina before I start lifting weights.
When I say boxing for fitness, the general idea I have is not to go to a boxing gym and fight but rather to train using boxing methods i.e.(skipping, using punching bags and shadow boxing) as it is much more intense training than that of wrestling.
I have absolutely no intention to even spar within the gym let alone fight.

I would very much appreciate an opinion on this.
Jazakallah

Comment: Would you have to hit someone hit on the face during practice, if not in a real match? That is one of the main criteria that boxing is not recommended as the Prophet forbade hitting an opponent on the face.

Comment: like I said in my question I wouldn't even be sparring, my main concern was that ultimately, if boxing is haram, would learning how to box or practicing boxing by yourself be inherently haram as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no evidence to prohibit what you mentioned of

> skipping, using punching bags and shadow boxing

Therefore its halal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).